# Extract only populated values of Partial<T> and ignore undefined values

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-types, typescript-utility

I have some model that tracks the "completed" status of a few pages (notice that none of the fields are optional, which is a must for the use case):

```js
interface IncompletPages {
  page1: boolean;
  page2: boolean;
  page3: boolean;
  page4: boolean;
}
```

In my component, I have a local object of this interface which controls the active `router-outlet` (i.e. it only enables the main `router-outlet` once all pages are complete). By default, they all start as false, meaning the primary `router-outlet` will be used, but at the creation of the component, an API call will return an instance of `IncompletePages` which may have some of them set to true.

```js
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {

  pagesToComplete: IncompletPages = {
    page1 = false,
    page2 = false,
    page3 = false,
    page4 = false,
  };

  constructor(private mySvc: MyService) {
    mySvc.getIncompletePages().subscribe({
      next: (pages: IncompletePage) => {
        this.pagesToComplete = pages;
      },
    });
  }
}
```

From here I would like each of these pages to notify the `pagesToComplete` object when they have completed by sending an object with their property and boolean value, but with *only* their property. To do this, I've added a simple getter and setter to my service:

```js
export class MyService {
  private complete$: Observable<Partial<IncompletePages>>;
  private comleteSubscriber: Subscriber<Partial<IncompletePages>>;

  constructor() {
    this.complete$ = new Observable<Partial<IncompletePages>>(completeSubsciber => {
      this.completeSubscriber = completeSubsciber;
    });
  }

  getIncompletePages() {
    // return result of API call
  }

  getCompletedNotification() {
    return this.complete$;
  }

  setCompletedNotification(completed: Partial<IncompletePages>) {
    this.completeSubscriber.next(completed);
  }
}
```

So each page, once completed, should do something like `mySvc.setCompletedNotification({page1: true});` when it has finished. This will emit on the `complete$` observable in the service, which `MyComponent` will pick up on with an open subscription to `getCompletedNotification()`, as in the following:

```js
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {

  pagesToComplete: // ...

  constructor(private mySvc: MyService) {
    // ...
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.mySvc
      .getCompletedNotification()
      .pipe(
        tap((pages: Partial<IncompletePages>) => {
          // And here's my question (below)
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Now with all that setup out of the way, my question is, is there a concise way I can update a *single* value in `pagesToComplete` without rewriting the entire object? Something like `this.pagesToComplete[keyof pages] = [keyof pages].value;`? I know that using `<Partial<T>>` will make all properties of `<T>` optional, and when sending a `<Partial<T>>`, it will make all the other properties undefined. However, I don't want to reset the other values in my local object to undefined, but just update the one that was passed.

For now I've settled on re-writing the entire object every time with the help of the nullish coalescing operator:

```js
(pages) => {
  this.pagesToComplete = {
    page1: pages.page1 ?? this.pagesToComplete.page1,
    page1: pages.page2 ?? this.pagesToComplete.page2,
    page1: pages.page3 ?? this.pagesToComplete.page3,
    page1: pages.page4 ?? this.pagesToComplete.page4,
  };
}
```

but this feels unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, would this work?

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {

  pagesToComplete: // ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mySvc
      .getCompletedNotification()
      .pipe(
        tap((pages: Partial<IncompletePages>) => {
          this.pagesToComplete = {...this.pagesToComplete, ...pages };
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

[Check this code in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgQewLYAcA2EYACnAOYQDOyA3gFDLK7kQCMAXMgEaaaFwgA3AyYsATJx58IA4Y2YUAzJN78hIhRAAsK6bLoBfOnQT44lagFkAngGEcuTCAjhax%20S0oAVTPbyFITnQsfyJSCmoAXjdGDwoOZHh8SggAGhE4iAlEuGS0jNElTiSU9NjC7WLc0pEDYREAega0AHJsZEwAN2hKYH9gGFAyZDAAC2BqZigwZHYAEREwOFwACk1KTlJp4FyAHmCHAPCqAD4ASk5OzGAAExjYsYmAOnWfPwIiFGiaZCe-x8oL08b0On1Svz%2062QdVqhmMWBAlBmIUczlc0WcAHdkDZ3k4XGAVmdhAjKNInvhMGQVij8eAgREQaFIMTkE1kABBfD4ZBwKAoEoQeEOOlgJ5LVY-TTZMBQACuKAMxJMTjJhApVJpIrRYtevlBLMEbOaXJ5fIF1RQXDlM2lwrwovFyxWUpYCVlCvB0qqeS9LGUI3laQqOkDCuhytJ5Mp1NpOoZVCZH0NxrQIG6UBSd0wMG4EBgmH59tRBKdkoqAcFfooocFEZJqujmrjpb17wCEFZ7IA8iB8NYKqw80MwxAgA)

Comment: Looking at the playground (is that a new feature? I just started seeing that today, and I've never seen it before, but I also don't go to that site much), it does indeed look like what I'm looking for! I would've thought that using the spread operator on both of those objects would append one to the other, ending up with duplicate properties, but even as I write this it occurs to me that that would cause typing conflicts since `pagesToComplete` is explicitly defined as having *only* those four properties. I ended up settling for lodash's `assign()`, but it's great to know a native method too!

Comment: Yes, you can't have duplicate keys in an object. This is why I placed `...pages` at the end. The later object overrides the first one (you can look at it as stacking objects one on top of another). You `assign()` solution is a good one too (btw, it is based on the native code `Object.assign()`) with the added benefit of keeping the original object's type (it didn't look like it mattered on you scenario but it could matter in others).

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do recall reading that in the lodash docs. That was the first I'd heard of the native function (can you tell I'm still new-ish at this? :) ), so six of one, half a dozen of the other as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Yes, exactly, from what I understand from your case, it doesn't matter what solution you use, it will give you the same result. You only need to be mindful if you need to maintain the type of the object you are assigning into. In those cases, you need to use the `assign()` or `Object.assign()`. Good luck with your TS journey! We all have started somewhere and, in fact, I didn't start that long ago either to be honest :D